# Simulate press in a link using keystroke

Tags: javascript, html

Hello  I have this link for example

```
<a href"http://google.es">Link</a>
```

Is there any way using Javascript or similar that when I press for example the number 5 in the keyboard It´s the same as if I press the link with the mouse?
Thanks

Comment: You can use Mouse Events.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery

`$( document ).keypress(function( event ) {
    event.charCode == 53 ? window.open("google.es","_self") : console.log('another key');
  });`

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `keypress` event and sniff out the `event.which` and when the appropriate key is pressed you can programmatically click the `a` or link element.

Check this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/mWyymV) for the example.
Note: This example is using `jQuery` plugin.

Comment: Thanks is It possible to use with numbers higher than 9 for example if I press 18?

Comment: I've updated my CodePen, please take a look. Now, it will trigger the link click when the digit 1 and 8 is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Using jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function checkKey(e) {
        var code;

        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;

        if (code == 53) { // replace the 53 with the keycode of your choice.
            $('#myLink').trigger("click");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="checkKey(event);">
<button id="myLink" onclick="window.location.href= 'https://google.com'">Link</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Keycode reference: http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can use the key press event in jquery

```
$(function() {
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 53){
    location.href = "http://google.es";
    }        
  });
});
```

this is for the key 5 if you want to change key give asci value for that key